# Datagridview update cell value based on another cell value

Tags: c#, datagridview, calculated-columns

if I have DataGrid with 4 columns as you can see

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4    
5000   -     -    3250    
3250   -     -    2300    
2300   -     -    result
```

Col1 has a value and Col2 and Col3 make a formula on that value Col4 print the result.
I want to set that result to the next cell on Col1 and again Col2,3 apply the formula and so on.

I have tried the next snippet code but It's applied on all cells in the column.

```
for (int i = 1; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = result;
}
```

Comment: Why [repost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58239580/1070452)?  You are almost certainly going to get the same advice. [DataColumn.Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I reposted the question to describe it in another way. and also I tried to delete the previous question to avoid the disturbance. thanks for your re-advice

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit difficult to understand what you're looking for. It seems you want to enter a result of Column3 from a previous row into a next row. That can be done like this:

C#:

```
for (var ir = 1; ir <= dgv.Rows.Count - 1; ir++)   // note we're starting on the *2nd* row
{
    dgv.Rows(ir).Cells("Col1").Value = dgv.Rows(ir - 1).Cells("Col3").Value;// or another result from your previous row...
}
```

VB.NET:

```
    For ir = 1 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1   ' note we're starting on the *2nd* row
        dgv.Rows(ir).Cells("Col1").Value = dgv.Rows(ir - 1).Cells("Col3").Value   ' or another result from your previous row...
    Next
```

Instead of looping whole `DataGridview`, you could also add a computation of a single `DataGridViewCell` (cells), to a proper event. But you won't notice performance differences, unless you have lots of rows.

You can also simplify the syntax using defined rows or cells, like this:

```
DataGridViewRow dr;
dr = dgv.Rows(ir);
```

and apply it:

```
dr.Cells("Col1").value = result;
```

Furthermore, you should be doing operations on values on the `DataTable` set to DataGridView's `DataSource`, not on the `DataGridView` itself. To avoid running into wrong data types, due to performance (when you have lots of rows), etc.